# Working code below to fetch all the data from my MongoDb databse but now I want to only fetch based on lets say courses category. How can I do it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below is a working code that I used to fetch all my data from my MongoDb database. It worked fine and now I am looking to only fetch based on certain criteria. Lets say I have list of courses with title, description, category, and price. I want to only show the ones with category that says 'coding. How can I do it?
This is React Code

```js
import "./style/courses.css";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import './style/home.css';

function Course() {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/courses")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCourses(data); // set users in state
      });
  }, []); // empty array because we only run once



  return (
    courses.map(course => {
      return ( <
        div className = "main"
        key = {
          course._id
        } >
        <
        div className = "product" >
        <
        img src = {
          course.image
        }
        alt = {
          course.title
        }
        />

        <
        div className = "product__info" >
        <
        p className = "info__name" > {
          course.title
        } < /p> <
        p className = "info__name" > {
          course.category
        } < /p>

        <
        p className = "info__description" > {
          course.description.substring(0, 100)
        }... < /p>

        <
        p className = "info__price" > $ {
          course.price
        } < /p>


        <
        Link to = {
          `/courses/${course._id}`
        }
        className = "info__button" >


        View <
        /Link>

        <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        /div>
      )
    })
  )
}
export default Course;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is backend routes

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router= express.Router()

const categoryController = require("../controllers/categorycontroller.js");

router.route('/').get(categoryController.findCategory);

module.exports=router
```

with initial route

app.use('/courses/category', categoryeRoute)

This is controller

```js
const Category = require("../models/course");

//find course by category
exports.findCategory = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const Categoryquery = req.query.category;
      const firstCategory = await Category.find({category:Categoryquery});
      res.send(firstCategory);
    } catch {
      res.status(404).send({ error: "category is not found!" });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You wrote all that code, so what keeps you from adding the feature you need? Or did you just copy the code from someone else? Have you worked through any tutorials concerning the use of MongoDB? Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry if I broke any rules or guidelines, but to answer your questions, yes I wrote all the code from the backend to the frontend part. It is part of a project I am working through the ones I posted here are just part that is related to my question. I have been learning MERN for around a month now so I am still fresh to the more advanced concepts

Answer (score 0):

Your code is excellent...
This line `const firstCategory = await Category.find({category:Categoryquery})`
When using your postman or any software you used to test your API I believe for the category you must have used a direct value like `const firstCategory = await Category.find({category:"science"})` this will in turn display only science category.

But the major reason why your code isn't working is because of you need to send a value to filter the courses since when you already have this line

```
const Categoryquery = req.query.category;
```

I suggest using a drop-down with all the categories in the frontend. So that you can inturn use onChange to pass the category value to the backend. But `req.query` here simply means you will extract the data from your url.

[Check this out](https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/)